# Automated Field Update

Tags: apex

In which way can I update custom date field automatically after 7 days without using Time-dependent workflow trigger depending on which my trigger will fire and sends an reminder email?

So, is there way to update field automatically after a spam of time

Comment: Why don't you want to use time based workflow?

Comment: I am converting lead. So, while converting status it is showing error that 'Unable to convert lead that is in use by workflow'.

Comment: You could have a scheduled job which executes regularly and checks for leads which are have reached the 7 day limit and not been converted, would that work?

Comment: So, where to write that scheduled job? And trigger should only fire when stage is open.

Comment: how to check that condition in schedule job and fire trigger

Comment: Or can I schedule job to update field automatically?Depending on which my trigger will fire

Answer (score 0):

At it's simplest you could write a scheduled job which selected records which match your requirements (date and that the stage is open etc) and then updates the field which you are using currently to fire your trigger.

That means you leverage the existing field update / trigger and just have a small scheduled job to cause an update.

To do this you would write an apex class implementing the schedulable interface (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex_scheduling_1.htm) and then schedule it to run when you require.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule a batch class for updating your date field weekly.

Comment: Suppose reminder email date is custom field which needs to be changed. So, how to write batch class for that

Comment: For Lead we need to write batch class to update reminder email date. How to write class to update?

Comment: But that field should be updated automatically after 7 days

Comment: Should not update immediately

Answer (score 0):

//batch class syntax

```
global class class_Name Implements Database.Batchable <sObject> {
global Database.queryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    String SOQL = 'SELECT Id FROM sObject';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(SOQL);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sObject> scope) {
list<sObject> listToUpdate = new list<sObject>();
for(sObject listObj : scope)
{
Datefield__c = updatedvalue;
listToUpdate.add(Datefield__c);
}

}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
}
```

}

//Schedule class syntax

```
 global class Scheduler_Btach_ContactToUpdateIsActive implements Schedulable   {

public static string sched = '0 0 12 ? * SUN *';

global static String scheduleMe() {
    Scheduler_Btach_ContactToUpdateIsActive SC = new Scheduler_Btach_ContactToUpdateIsActive(); 
    return System.schedule('My batch Job', sched, SC);
}

global void execute (SchedulableContext SC){
     class_Name class_NameObj = new  class_Name();
     database.executeBatch(class_NameObj);

}
```

The above schedule class will update your date custom field weekly on sunday.
Just execute anonymous a command in devloper console after this:

```
Scheduler_Btach_ContactToUpdateIsActive schedObj = new  Scheduler_Btach_ContactToUpdateIsActive();
schedObj.scheduleMe();
```

Comment: But lead cannot be converted inbetween till scheduled jobs are completed. So, we need an way that field will be automatically updated after 7 days and also lead can be converted whenever we want. Thank U!